# How to fetch the images from server

Tags: android, image, listview

```
class LoadLatest extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{

    ProgressDialog mProgress;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {

    mProgress=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.mContext);
    mProgress.setTitle("Fetech Latest Videos");
    mProgress.setMessage("Please Wait...");
    mProgress.setCancelable(false);
    mProgress.show();
}   


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try{
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            String url="http://twominenglish.com/api/getlatest?";
            //http://twominenglish.com/api/getlatest?page=1
            JSONArray IdArray = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url+"page="+page);
            mLatestList.clear();
            for(int i=0;i<IdArray.length();i++){

                try{
                     JSONObject jObject;
                     mLtest=new Latest();
                     jObject=IdArray.getJSONObject(i);
                     mLtest.SetID(jObject.getString("ID"));
                     //mLtest.SetImageUrl(jObject.getString("ImageURL"));
                     String path="http://twominenglish.com"+jObject.getString("ImageURL");
                     mLtest.SetImageUrl(path);
                     mLtest.SetDescription(jObject.getString("Description"));
                     mLtest.SetTitle(jObject.getString("Title"));
                     mLatestList.add(mLtest);
                     mLtest=new Latest();
                }catch(JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }


        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
```

//mY ADAPTER CLASS

```
public class LatestAdapter extends BaseAdapter{


private static ArrayList<Latest> ArrayList;
private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater mInflater=null;
private Context mContext;
AvatarDownloader ad;
public ImageLoader mImageLoader;
public LatestAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Latest> results) {
    activity =context;
    ArrayList = results;
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    //mContext=context;
    mImageLoader=new ImageLoader(context.getApplicationContext());
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return ArrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return ArrayList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.latest_category, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.tv_Title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtsubcatTitle);         
        holder.imgvw_pic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_pic);
         //ad=new AvatarDownloader(mContext);
        mImageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity);
        mImageLoader.DisplayImage(ArrayList.get(position).GetImageUrl(), ArrayList.get(position).GetTitle(), null, holder.imgvw_pic);
        String url=ArrayList.get(position).GetImageUrl().toString();
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.tv_Title.setText(ArrayList.get(position).GetTitle());



    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView tv_Title;
    ImageView imgvw_pic;
}
```

Can anyone help this is my adapter class it taking 20 url from ArrayList when i fetech the image through image loader it run only 7 Times only. what i do.please help me..

Comment: Take a look on Volley: https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325304728

Comment: @shreyas  i putting my code please help me.i have 20 url's when i fetech image it will only 7 times only where is the prblem please help me.

Comment: @EvZ- i putting my code please help me.i have 20 url's when i fetech image it will only 7 times only where is the prblem please help me

Comment: @Tarsem-please help me for this code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the folowing for that

1) LAZY LIST- https://github.com/thest1/LazyList

2) Universal Image LOader - https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

3) Volley- if you  saw google io-2013 video. volley is supposed to very fast.

Comment: -i already using LazyList code for downloading images.i dont know where is the prblm why is not downloaded all the images please check my code i already posted here-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785437/how-to-parser-json-for-image-url/17802412?noredirect=1#17802412 waiting for your reply thanks a lot